# Low Search + Matrix field data

Tags: low-search

I'm trying to create a dropdown of matrix field data using the search form. It's outputting the matrix data, but I can't seem to figure out how to remove duplicate content. Say I'm using the data "john doe" on multiple entries -- it's showing for every entry, not just once. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks in advance.

```
{exp:low_search:form query="{segment_3}"}   
    <label>Arranger:</label>
    <select name="search:tags:arranger">
        {exp:channel:entries channel="products" dynamic="no"}
            {tags}<option value="{arranger}">{arranger}</option>{/tags}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
{/exp:low_search:form}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use [the Query module](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/query/) for this. Something like

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT DISTINCT col_id_X AS val FROM exp_matrix_data WHERE field_id = Y ORDER BY val"}
  <option>{val}</option>
{/exp:query}
```

...where you need to replace `X` with the correct column ID and `Y` with the correct field ID.

**EDIT** Alternatively, you can try this query:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT col_id_X AS val FROM exp_matrix_data WHERE field_id = Y AND col_id_X != '' GROUP BY col_id_X ORDER BY val"}
  <option>{val}</option>
{/exp:query}
```

Comment: Thanks, Low! I'm still getting an error though. The column is 'arranger' and the field is 'tags'. Here is the error: 

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'arranger' in 'field list'

SELECT DISTINCT arranger AS val FROM exp_matrix_data WHERE field_id = tags ORDER BY val

Filename: modules/query/mod.query.php

Line Number: 53

Comment: You need the **numeric** IDs here. Not the short-names. So, for example, `col_id_5` and `field_id = 8` if those IDs are 5 and 8. Go to the Matrix' field settings. There you can see the field_id in the URL. To get to the col_id, view the page source and look for it.

Comment: ...or look up the IDs using the SQL Manager: browse the `exp_channel_fields` and `exp_matrix_cols` tables.

Comment: Got em, but still having an issue. It's showing the items 4 times. Here's the code:

{exp:query sql="SELECT DISTINCT col_id_25 AS val FROM exp_matrix_data WHERE field_id = 117 ORDER BY val"}
        <option>{val}</option>
     {/exp:query}

Comment: Try the second query I just added. Also, make sure the values are indeed the same (no trailing spaces etc).

Comment: That looks like it fixed it. I had it wrapped in the channel entry tag and that was causing an issue. Thank you so much for your help, Low!!!!