# Low Search + Matrix field data = display search term

Tags: low-search

I've got the search working great, as solved here:
[Low Search + Matrix field data](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/30373/low-search-matrix-field-data)

But now I'd like to display the query on the results page. Technically I am displaying it by using this:

Searched for **{low_search_query_string}**

but it looks like a string -- of course. Is there a way to make it pretty and just show the search term?

Thanks!

:osa

Comment: What do you mean by "looks like a string"? An example of what it looks like and what you want it to look like would help a lot!

Comment: I searched "Packaged Shipment" -- here's what the result looks like:

?search:tags:delivery_method=Packaged+Shipment

Answer (score 1):

As per [how parameters work in Low Search](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/parameters#params), you can output any parameter with a variable formatted like this:

```
{low_search_parameter_name}
```

As per the question/answer you linked to, that would be:

```
{low_search_search:tags:arranger}
```

Comment: So If I wanted to output the results for all of the tags? Can I use an "or" operator? Not sure how to output for any of the tags.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can want to output the search results or all the tags? Can you elaborate (edit your original question)?